# How to setup gitblit in windows

Tags: git, gitblit

We need GIT server in our local server. After searched on the internet, we decided to use `Gitblit` which is easy to install.

But we have problems when we want to access the `Gitblit` from other machines. As the setup documents mentioned in the **Creating your own Self-Signed Certificate**', we should '**Set your hostname into the HOSTNAME variable.** Here is my makekeystore.cmd file.

```
@SET HOSTNAME=my-server-ip<br/>
@del keystore<br/>
@java -cp gitblit.jar;"%CD%\ext\*" com.gitblit.MakeCertificate --hostname %HOSTNAME% --subject "CN=%HOSTNAME%, OU=Gitblit, O=Gitblit, L=Some Town, ST=Some State, C=US"
```

And we have update the gitblit.properties as followed

```
server.httpBindInterface = my server ip
server.httpsBindInterface = my server ip
server.httpPort = 9090
server.httpsPort = 9443
```

After this settings, we still can't access the Gitblit. When we input the http: `my-server-ip:9090` the page can't be opened.

If we change all this values back to localhost and input http: //localhost:9090, it works.

So is there anyone know how to setup Gitblit, I have read the official document many times, but no results. Who can give me a simple?

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Have you checked the firewall on the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
server.httpBindInterface = my server ip
server.httpsBindInterface = my server ip
```

Those values allow you to configure Gitblit to bind to a particular network adapter by it's local ip address.  You do not specify an outside/external ip address here.  If you don't care about binding to a particular network adapter, you can leave those settings blank and Gitblit will serve 9090 and 9443 on all local network adapters available on the server.